# Why does Spring create a transaction when calling a @Transactional Propagation.NEVER method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-test, spring-transactions

I have an integration test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {CarWebServiceApplication.class, CarTestHelper.class})
@Slf4j
public class CarRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired 
    private CarTestHelper carTestHelper;

    @Test
    public void aSimpleTest() {
        carTestHelper.simpleTest();
    }
}
```

`CarTestHelper`:

```
@TestComponent
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CarTestHelper {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER,  transactionManager ="carTransactionManager")
    public void simpleTest() {
    }

}
```

After setting logging level to:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa: trace
org.springframework.transaction: trace
```

I see

> TRACE 17920 --- [           main]
> t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method
> 'com.example.repository.CarTestHelper.simpleTest' with attribute:
> PROPAGATION_NEVER,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'carTransactionManager'
>
> TRACE 17920 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           :
> Getting transaction for
> [com.example.repository.CarTestHelper.simpleTest]
>
> TRACE 17920 --- [
> main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing
> transaction for [com.example.repository.CarTestHelper.simpleTest]

From the API, I see that Propagation.NEVER means:

> Execute non-transactionally, throw an exception if a transaction exists.

But why do the logs indicate that the method is transactional and it is getting and completing a transaction when the method is called? Is the method actually being executed transactionally meaning that the API Javadoc is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

NEVER means that an exception should be thrown if a transaction is ALREADY active not that a transaction should never been started.